# Wrong Directory for Java JRE

Tags: java, command-line

When I am trying to run my Modular Audio Recognition Framework (MARF) jar files, it gives me the message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\i386\jvm.cfg

I see that the directory it is trying to look for the file is incorrect. I have an updated Java jre folder in Program Files. Is there a way to redirect it?

I have tried going to the Environment variables and none actually point to this folder.

```
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
```

Comment: What are the CLASSPATH, PATH and JAVA_HOME variables?

Comment: CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60   JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60   PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin

Comment: Which directory do you want it to point to? Are you sure that is the whole value of PATH and CLASSPATH variables?

Comment: Yes those are the whole values. I want to it point Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111 where the updated Java is. However, since the 1.8.0_65 isn't a folder in my program files, I am unsure why it is shown.

Comment: Maybe jre1.8.0_60 is pointing (linked) to jre1.8.0_65 folder. Have you checked that?

Comment: Older (Oracle) Java versions on Windows updated PATH etc for each version; recent versions instead put symlinks under %allusersprofile% which is conventionally c:\programdata in oracle\java\javapath and put only that fixed 'switch' location in PATH. If you've installed 8u111 I'm surprised this didn't happen automatically; you might try uninstalling, cleaning any leftover bits manually, and installing again to see if that works better. In any case CLASSPATH does not need to and should not point to the JRE; the JRE uses BOOTCLASSPATH for its own stuff.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh How would I go about checking that?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I believe the older Java uninstalled when I installed the newer version. Is there any reason why it wouldn't be updating on its own? I wouldn't think it's due to the program.

Comment: Could you please also post how you start your application.

Comment: Older Java Windows packaging used an installation process where each update replaced the previous one, but _recent_ updates of 8 do not. Look at ControlPanel / ProgramsAndFeatures (aka `appwiz.cpl`) under J to see what you do or don't have installed.

Comment: @SubOptimal I just java -jar SpeakerIdent.jar (name of the file)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 According to the list, I have Java 8 Update 111, and Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 60

Comment: @LeslieKnowsBest for linking of directories you should have a look at http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/linux-ln-command-examples and check if the jre directory is linked to each other or not?

Answer (score 0):

What happen if you run following from the command line?

- set environment variables

  ```
  set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60
  set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
  ```
- check the Java version

  ```
  java -version
  ```
- run your application

  ```
  java -jar SpeakerIdent.jar
  ```